# SQL Server UNION ALL Merge Join (Concatenation) too slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union-all

I have a select query which utilizes `UNION ALL` keyword on two tables with same structure (columns and primary key, they have different non-clustered indexes). These two tables contain 39 million rows, a million in one and a 38 million in the other. When running a query just on a `table1` which has a million rows, it takes approximately 0.2 seconds, on `table2`  we have a different situation it takes from 0.5 to 1.2 seconds maximum, depending on the stress of DB.

In reality, for displaying I need to union those two tables, but the problem is that the union query takes a whopping 8 seconds to run. When taking a look at execution plan, the most heavy operation is `Merge Join (Concatenation)` with the cost of 91%, I am little bit concerned as the `WHERE` clause I'm running selects 51 entries from `table1` and 0 entries from the `table2` (larger table).

I can't get my head around it, I've been trying to find any solutions to my problem for last two days now and all I found was either `UNION` being used instead of `UNION ALL` or unnecessary clauses being in place like `GROUP BY` or `LEFT/INNER JOINS`. Query also does paging, using this commands `ORDER BY [Id] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;`, all tests (on single tables and with `UNION ALL`) were performed with paging (`OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT`) keywords in place.

If required, I can provide the table details and query details. It a simple select query with 2 `INNER JOINS` and 2 `LEFT JOINS` all of the joined tables contain really small amount of data (ranging from 50 entries to 20K entries).

---

Here's the query

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (SELECT    tr.Id, 
        tr.Amount, 
        tr.TypeId, 
        t.Name AS [Type], 
        tr.Date, 
        tr.ExternalKey, 
        tr.ExternalDescription, 
        tr.GameId, 
        tr.GameProviderId, 
        gp.Name AS GameProvider, 
        u.Username, 
        u.Pincode, 
        gp.Name, 
        g.GameName, 
        u.OperatorId, 
        tr.BalanceBefore,
        tr.BalanceAfter,
        tr.UserId
FROM ( 
        SELECT    *
              FROM      dbo.ActiveTransactions at
              WHERE    ( 1 = 1 )
         AND ( [Date] >= '2017-07-17 20:00:00' )
         AND ( [TypeId] != 10 )
         AND ( [UserId] = 29041 )
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    *
              FROM      dbo.TransactionHistory th --WITH(INDEX(IX_TransactionHistory_DateType_UserId))
              WHERE    ( 1 = 1 )
         AND ( [Date] >= '2017-07-17 20:00:00' )
         AND ( [TypeId] != 10 )
         AND ( [UserId] = 29041 )
            ) AS tr 

INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON tr.UserId = u.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.GameProviders gp ON tr.GameProviderId = gp.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Games g ON tr.GameId = g.GameId AND tr.GameProviderId = g.ProviderId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Types t ON tr.TypeId = t.Id     ) AS t
ORDER BY [Id] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: What's a paragraph ? I'll include the queries.

Comment: Consider repeating the joins and filtering on the activetransactions and transactionhistory separately before the union and then union the results. This should take ..2 + .5 to 1.2  and complete in under 2 seconds.  It saves the union action until after the data has been filtered.

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess: without knowledge of indexes or execution plan on what the engine is actually getting caught up on.

Consider: Doing the union after the joins/filters instead of before: you have to repeat the joins but you may gain some index efficiency's lost in a unioned set processing.

In this case I created two CTE's and then unioned them.

as I'm unable to really test this, I may have some syntax errors.

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(SELECT    tr.Id, 
        tr.Amount, 
        tr.TypeId, 
        t.Name AS [Type], 
        tr.Date, 
        tr.ExternalKey, 
        tr.ExternalDescription, 
        tr.GameId, 
        tr.GameProviderId, 
        gp.Name AS GameProvider, 
        u.Username, 
        u.Pincode, 
        gp.Name, 
        g.GameName, 
        u.OperatorId, 
        tr.BalanceBefore,
        tr.BalanceAfter,
        tr.UserId
FROM ( 
        SELECT    *
              FROM      dbo.ActiveTransactions at
              WHERE    ( 1 = 1 )
         AND ( [Date] >= '2017-07-17 20:00:00' )
         AND ( [TypeId] != 10 )
         AND ( [UserId] = 29041 )) AS tr 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON tr.UserId = u.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.GameProviders gp ON tr.GameProviderId = gp.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Games g ON tr.GameId = g.GameId AND tr.GameProviderId = g.ProviderId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Types t ON tr.TypeId = t.Id     ) AS t),
CTE2 as (
SELECT  tr.Id, 
        tr.Amount, 
        tr.TypeId, 
        t.Name AS [Type], 
        tr.Date, 
        tr.ExternalKey, 
        tr.ExternalDescription, 
        tr.GameId, 
        tr.GameProviderId, 
        gp.Name AS GameProvider, 
        u.Username, 
        u.Pincode, 
        gp.Name, 
        g.GameName, 
        u.OperatorId, 
        tr.BalanceBefore,
        tr.BalanceAfter,
        tr.UserId

FROM (SELECT    *
      FROM dbo.TransactionHistory th --WITH(INDEX(IX_TransactionHistory_DateType_UserId))
      WHERE    ( 1 = 1 )
         AND ( [Date] >= '2017-07-17 20:00:00' )
         AND ( [TypeId] != 10 )
         AND ( [UserId] = 29041 ) as tr
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON tr.UserId = u.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.GameProviders gp ON tr.GameProviderId = gp.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Games g ON tr.GameId = g.GameId AND tr.GameProviderId = g.ProviderId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Types t ON tr.TypeId = t.Id) AS t
)
SELECT * from CTE1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * from CTE2
ORDER BY [Id] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;
```